# Yii2 Advanced Displaying and Saving fields of two tables in one form

Tags: database, relational-database, relationship, yii2-advanced-app

How can I Display fields of different Tables in one form and saving it at once in the database...The scenario is when i get a new form to fill up, this two tables will merge in the same FORM and probably save at the same time. The second problem is, "id"(PK) of "form" will generate number incrementally after saving. Question is how can i copy the value of "id"(PK) in "form" to "forminfo_info"(FK) while saving... Please need assistance on this..

[image]

Comment: You could show the image actually...

Comment: You can view the image. it was linked in the text...

Comment: Nvm, I have done it for you. The point is to make the image and your question in the same page such that people can find it easier to see the image and link it to your question. Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Thank you... Kindly help me in this please? The scenario is when i get a new form to fill up, this two tables will merge in the same form and probably save at the same time. The second problem is, "id" of "form" will generate number incrementally after saving. Question is how can i copy the value of id in form to forminfo_info(FK) while saving... Please need assistance on this...

Comment: No, I don't understand the question actually. But I got to see your post because I was doing reviewing on "First Posts". That's why I only commented on your question's *format*. Sorry...

Comment: Ok. But thanks anyway..... Their's anyone who could help me in this???????

Comment: There *should* be someone who can help you... But more importantly is to get your post viewed by more people if you want to improve the chance of your question getting seen and you got the help you need. One way to do it is by adding the tag with more popular, but *relevant* tag - not just a particular technology. Like database, yii2, etc... But be careful with putting your question too. Bad/duplicate question tends to get downvoted and/or closed very quickly if noticed by more. So, please put good questions, avoid duplicate question (do search on the site), and add relevant tag. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of your question is really explained [here in the Yii2 guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-multiple-models.html).

Anyway here is what I would try in your actionUpdate/actionCreate-controller. 
(Note: this code is not tested so it might need some fixes, but overall structure should work.)

```
// Create empty models, typically for actionCreate()
$m1 = new Model();
$m2 = new AnotherModel();

// ...or load models using ids for actionUpdate($m1Id, $m2Id)
$m1 = Model::findOne($m1Id);
$m2 = AnotherModel::findOne($m2Id);

// Try to populate the models from the request
if ($m1->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $m2->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    // Models now loaded, but not validated
    if ($m1->validate() && $m2->validate()) {
         // Both models are now validated, save the first one
         $m1->save(false);    // No need to validate again
         // Now Model has an id, save its id as a reference in AnotherModel
         $m2->m1Id = $m1->id;
         // ...or create a method in your Model-model for setting the foreign key
         // $m2->connectModel($m1);  // The fancier object oriented way
         $m2->save(false);   // Set true if you validate the foreign key
    }
}

// Return view for rendering
```

If any of the two save-operations fails (not tested in the code) that is sort of a fatal error that probably should be handled. Worst case you could end up with one model saved and not the other, although it should be unlikely if validation pass. Look into transactions for "atomic" saving (all or nothing save) if your database supports it, or just leave it (I think most just leave it or logs an error for later).